# How to return value from onPostExecute and displaying in the MainActivity using Android?

Tags: android, background, android-asynctask

I am writing a code in Android to print a value process in background thread using Async task. I am displaying the value in the background thread on onPostExecute function. But i want to display the value in the MainActivity after completing the background process.

**Java Code**

```
package com.example.mydoinbackground;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

TextView tt;

String x , y ,z;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

    x = "Android";

    y = "Apple";

    z = "Microsoft";

    MyTest mt = new MyTest();

    mt.execute();

            /// I want to display the result here ///

}

private class MyTest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {

                String z1 = x+" "+y+" "+z;

                return z1;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {

                tt.setText(result);

        }

}}
```

So , this is above code. I am getting the proper result in onPostExecute and it displaying correctly but I want to display the result in onCreate MainActivity.

Please suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to do it is to start a `ProgressDialog` when you start the `AsyncTask`, Initialize and show the `ProgressDialog` in the `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`. After the result is obtained `hide()` the `ProgressDialog` and use the result like this:

```
somevalue = new MyTask().execute();
```

[this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/) and the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) will be useful to you